# What's the right column in the bounties tab for?

Tags: support

The right column in the bounties view has a column that I don't understand.  [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763356/veedrac?tab=bounties&sort=earned) of the place I'm talking about.

The context in the circled example: user **Veedrac** earned a bounty, and I'm not sure what user **NightShadeQueen** has to do with anything there.

What's the data in that column supposed to be telling me? The table doesn't have a header.  It would make sense sense if it showed the date the bounty was earned, and the name of the user who had awarded it.

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15479928/revisions) you will see that [NightShadeQueen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5031339/nightshadequeen) was the one who placed and awarded the bounty to [Veedrac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763356/veedrac)

[image]

If we look at [How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-python) it appears that the column in the user profile is the user, date and time of the last activity on the post.  Also it looks as though only the bounty start counts towards the "activity" of the post.  So any action after the bounty was started is used as the date and time of last activity even if the bounty is awarded after that.

Comment: That's strange, when I mouse-over that bounty it says it was awarded by user `tripleee`

Comment: @wim are you looking at martin's answer or Veedrac's answer?  When I hover of the bounty award on Veedrac's answer it shows NightShadeQueen.

Comment: Oh you're right I was looking at the wrong answer.  There were two bounties on that question!!

Comment: What about the one below, about `__dunder__`?  That was my bounty, actually, but the right column is talking about user Kevin

Comment: @Kendra SO disagrees with you.  If you hover over active it gives july 23 17:09.  It looks like the bounty start is the only thing that counts towards the activity

Comment: Actually, after digging a bit more, I think you're right. It's really strange to me that the bounty start would count for that, but not the bounty end. I'll remove my comments.

Comment: @wim Your bounty started on Jun 5 at 15:12 but Kevin posted an answer on Jun 5 at 16:49 and then edited on Jun 12 at 14:45 which is the last activity on the post.  That is why you see Kevin in the right hand column.

Comment: I wonder what counts as "activity".  It does seem strange that awarding the bounty doesn't count as an activity.